# Python always drops NameError: name 'windll' is not defined even if I don't use it in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a macro for Piano Tiles 2 using some color-checking code and stuff. This is what I got:

```
def PixCol(i_x, i_y):
    import win32gui
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour)

def Start():
    from win32 import win32api
    from win32 import win32com
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    TileA = False
    TileB = False
    TileC = False
    TileD = False
    while True:
        # Color Checking
        if PixCol(1131, 473) == 0:
            TileA = True
        else:
            TileA = False

        if PixCol(1221, 473) == 0:
            TileB = True
        else:
            TileB = False

        if PixCol(1325, 473) == 0:
            TileC = True
        else:
            TileC = False

        if PixCol(1431, 473) == 0:
            TileD = True
        else:
            TileD = False

        # Auto Clicking
        if TileA == True:
            shell.sendKeys("a")

        if TileB == True:
            shell.sendKeys("s")

        if TileC == True:
            shell.sendKeys("d")

        if TileC == True:
            shell.sendKeys("f")

        # End Of Code
        if PixCol(1100, 60) == 15889441:
            break
```

I tried starting it with following commands.

```
>>> import PT2Macro
>>> PT2Macro.Start()
```

But instead of running it errored.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    PT2Macro.Start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\PT2Macro.py", line 22, in Start
    from win32 import win32com
NameError: name 'windll' is not defined
```

It drops the same error every time I try to run it, even though, I didn't use the windll module.

If you can, please help!

(My Specs)

```
Windows 7 64-bit
Python 3.4.3 x64
```

Comment: do you have the win32 module?

Comment: You're trying to import win32 - it needs windll. Presumably it comes along with the pywin32 installer. If you didn't use the installer, use it. If you did, please let us know.